# Wordpress: How to add a caption right-aligned to the edge of the image

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, caption

So how do I align an image caption under an image tag to it's right hand edge?

Tried using div but obviously that's not allowed in wp.

What alternative css/tags do I need to use?

Comment: Are you trying to right align ALL image captions on your site, or just a particular caption?

Comment: all image captions would do I guess - I take it you've got a plugin in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Asked](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/336325?replies=1) on Wordpress community site forum too, no response so presumably this isn't a feature of 2.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Does this not work?

.wp-caption p.wp-caption-text { text-align:right; }

Comment: sorry, I've not looked at the wordpress css files - so I had this to the css file and does wp add those classes automatically or do I add them on a span say myself?

Comment: WP will add those classes automatically when you create the caption.  You can check your theme's stylesheet to see if it already has a rule for the wp.caption-text class.  If so, you can modify that one. Or you could just paste the rule into the bottom of your stylesheet.

Comment: Oh, 2.2  I'm not sure about the caption support in that version.  I think the caption featured was reworked in 2.5 or 2.6.  But if you can give a URL to a page with one of your captions I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: cheers - http://aleatory.clientsideweb.net/2009/11/28/google-app-engine-datastore-gotchas/

Comment: OK, try this:

.wp-caption { text-align:right; display:block; }

Comment: nah still no luck.  I can't find any actual caption field for the image in this version of wp anyway so I imagine it's just not supported.  Thanks anyway for the pointer

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a way to specify alignment on a per-caption basis.

Basically, I copied the caption shortcode from the media.php and made it into my own custom function which accepts a "captionalign" argument.

To use, paste the below code into your theme's "function.php" file - this will allow you to specify an option in your caption tag named captionalign. By setting this to right, left, or center, you can specify a per-caption text alignment. Leaving out the attribute will have the caption default to whatever you have your default alignment as.

An example of this in use:

```
[caption align="aligncenter" width="300" caption="My caption" captionalign="right"]
<a href="http://www.myawesomeblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/image.jpg">
<img title="My image" src="http://www.myawesomeblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/image.jpg-300x216.jpg" alt="My image" width="300" height="216" />
</a>
[/caption]
```

And here is the function:

```
add_shortcode('wp_caption', 'custom_img_caption_shortcode');
add_shortcode('caption', 'custom_img_caption_shortcode');

/**
 * The Caption shortcode.
 *
 * Allows a plugin to replace the content that would otherwise be returned. The
 * filter is 'img_caption_shortcode' and passes an empty string, the attr
 * parameter and the content parameter values.
 *
 * The supported attributes for the shortcode are 'id', 'align', 'width', and
 * 'caption'.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 *
 * @param array $attr Attributes attributed to the shortcode.
 * @param string $content Optional. Shortcode content.
 * @return string
 */
function custom_img_caption_shortcode($attr, $content = null) {

// Allow plugins/themes to override the default caption template.
$output = apply_filters('img_caption_shortcode', '', $attr, $content);
if ( $output != '' )
    return $output;

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'id'    => '',
    'align' => 'alignnone',
    'width' => '',
    'caption' => '',
    'captionalign' => ''
), $attr));

if ( 1 > (int) $width || empty($caption) )
    return $content;

if ( $id ) $id = 'id="' . esc_attr($id) . '" ';

return '<div ' . $id . 'class="wp-caption ' . esc_attr($align) . '" style="width: ' . (10 + (int) $width) . 'px">'
. do_shortcode( $content ) . '<p class="wp-caption-text" style="text-align:' . $captionalign . '">' . $caption . '</p></div>';
}
```

Hope that helps someone!